# How to "free" QJsonObject that is member variable of QDialog instance?

Tags: qt

[QJsonObject's constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) doesn't receive a "parent" pointer as argument as many QObjects do. It also doesn't respond to "setParent". If a class has a member variable that is a QJsonObject, is it my responsibility to free it in the class' destructor? For example,

```
// In the .h
class ClassA : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ClassA(QWidget *pParent = 0);
private:
    QJsonObject *jsonObject;
}
// In the .cpp    
ClassA::ClassA(QWidget *pParent):QDialog(pParent)
{
  jsonObject = new QJsonObject;
  // Doesn't work:
  // jsonObject = new QJsonObject(this);
  // Also doesn't work
  // jsonObject->setParent(this);
}
```

Should I redefine ClassA's destructor and explicitly destroy the member variable `jsonObject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to create it in dynamic storage? Why not just make it a non-dynamic data member of `ClassA`?

```
class ClassA : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ClassA(QWidget *pParent = 0);
private:
    QJsonObject jsonObject; // note this is just a standard data member, not a pointer
}
```

Now when `ClassA` is destroyed, `jsonObject` will *also* be destroyed.

As a rule of thumb, you should always favour non-dynamic allocation where possible (that is, make it a normal data member), and so the lifetime of the object is managed by the enclosing object's scope.

If you have not heard of [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) (Resource Allocation is Initialisation), I would highly recommend reading up on it. It is one of the major tenets of C++.

Comment: Does QJsonObject allocate its internal data in the heap?

Comment: I don't know the internals of `QJsonObject`, but I would suspect yes - if the element it is representing is anything other than a fundamental type - such as a string, a json array or another json object, then it will more likely than not need to allocate, and typically this is done using the heap